# download an attachment from imap: BODY[1.3.1.2] and BODY.PEEK[1.3.1.2] return null

Tags: flutter, dart, imap

I need to download attachment from imap server in dart.

This is what I did:

- downloaded list of messages correctly with the command `(UID BODY.PEEK[HEADER] FLAGS)`;
- downloaded the single message correctly with the command `(UID BODY[] BODYSTRUCTURE ENVELOPE FLAGS)`

Now I need to download a single attachment of the message, and I am trying with both of the commands `(BODY[1.3.1.2])` and `(BODY.PEEK[1.3.1.2])` (btw which is the difference between these 2 commands? I do not know).

I use a library to get message, and I am pretty sure the path of the body is correct.

But when I launch both of the commands I didn't get the message.
This is the structure I get from the server (the structure is proprietary of the library):

```
msg = id: [592]\n
    headers = null
    _headerRaw = null
    _isParsed = false
    bodyRaw = null
    text = null
    parts = null
    _contentTypeHeader = null
    _contentDispositionHeader = null
    multiPartBoundary = null
    rawLines = null
    sequenceId = 592
    uid = null
    modSequence = null
    flags = null
    internalDate = null
    size = null
    _from = null
    _sender = null
    _replyTo = null
    _to = null
    _cc = null
    _bcc = null
    body = null
    envelope = null
```

**UPDATE**
This is the IMAP response. I tried to format it.

```
BODYSTRUCTURE
(
    (
        (text, plain, (charset, iso-8859-1), NIL, NIL, quoted-printable, 339, 8, NIL, (inline, NIL), NIL, NIL),
        (application, xml, (name, daticert.xml), NIL, NIL, base64, 1072, NIL, (inline, (filename, daticert.xml)), NIL, NIL),
        (message, rfc822, (name, postacert.eml), NIL, NIL, 7bit, 46914,
            (
                Fri, 31 Jul 2020 14:19:22 +0200, test message with pdf,
                (
                    (Team SRL, NIL, team, pec.net)
                ),
                (
                    (Team SRL, NIL, team, pec.net)
                ),
                (
                    (Team SRL, NIL, team, pec.net)
                ),
                (
                    (NIL, NIL, app.test1, test.example.com)
                ),
                NIL, NIL, NIL, <string.20200731141923.20215.06.1.15@pec-example.com>
            ),
            (
                (
                    (text, plain, (charset, iso-8859-15, format, flowed), NIL, NIL, quoted-printable, 799, 22, NIL, NIL, NIL, NIL),
                    (
                        (text, html, (charset, iso-8859-15), NIL, NIL, quoted-printable, 1708, 40, NIL, NIL, NIL, NIL),
                        (image, png, (name, logo team_300x87.png), <part1.1F93CB4D.4CD8B980@pec.example>, NIL, base64, 8632, NIL, (inline, (filename, logo team_300x87.png)), NIL, NIL),
                        related,
                        (boundary, ------------F1A74D7D44BD84106B4E0569),
                        NIL, NIL, NIL
                    ),
                    alternative,
                    (boundary, ------------6D98B2FDB8B24026063A27F9),
                    NIL, NIL, NIL
                ),
                (application, pdf, (name, MyPdf.pdf), NIL, NIL, base64, 33754, NIL, (attachment, (filename, MyPdf.pdf)), NIL, NIL),
                mixed,
                (boundary, ------------A5B0A8B4F69F8BD959B758D0),
                NIL, (it-IT), NIL
            ),
            810, NIL, (inline, (filename, postacert.eml)), NIL, NIL
        ),
        mixed,
        (boundary, ----------=_1596197964-20215-18),
        NIL, NIL, NIL
    ),
    (application, pkcs7-signature, (name, smime.p7s), NIL, NIL, base64, 9454, NIL, (attachment, (filename, smime.p7s)), NIL, NIL),
    signed,
    (protocol, application/pkcs7-signature, micalg, sha256, boundary, ----------=_1596197964-20215-19),
    NIL, NIL, NIL
)
```

I need to get MyPdf.pdf

Comment: Since this doesn't show us the actual structure of the messages, it's hard to tell what went wrong.  Four levels deep is fairly unusual.  PS: The difference with .PEEK is that it doesn't automatically set the \Seen (read) flag.

Comment: @Max is it right the command FETCH (BODY[...]) to get the content of an attachment?

Comment: Yes. BODY is to get the text of some part of the message, and the numeric specifier says what part.

Comment: @Max I updated my answer with Imap response. Can you check please how can I get Mypdf.pdf?